# jQuery slideDown() slideUp() require two clicks

Tags: jquery, click, slidedown, slideup

I've seen quite a few iterations of this question, but no solutions to my particular problem.

Issue occurs when clicking on an `h3` that's the trigger for toggling visibility on a list of links underneath. The selectors and behaviors work fine, showing the hidden items and hiding the others properly. Once a header's been clicked once, however, it must thereafter be clicked twice to perform the toggle. It's a small annoyance, but I'd like a solution.

So clicking on one header will slide it down if it's closed and up if it's open, adding and removing the `.active` class respectively… all good.

Clicking on another header will behave properly as well, hiding the open list and opening the clicked one.

But if you go *back* to the first header, previously opened but now closed, a single click on it will not initiate the toggles. It has to be clicked a second time.

That's the problem in a nutshell. I have limited access to the page code, so most of the traversing selecting has to be done in jQuery with the tags already in place.

Here's the page in question: 
http://queensvw.com/documents/stackoverflow

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hideAll() {
    $('#minutes_highlights .date_heading').nextAll('.document_listing').slideUp();
  }

  hideAll();

  $('#minutes_highlights .date_heading').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).nextUntil('hr').slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      hideAll();
      $(this).nextUntil('hr').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

I tried adding a `preventDefault()` and a `setTimeout()` based on other threads. To be honest I wasn't sure why they'd matter since I'm not acting on the `a`, but they didn't fix the click issue anyway.

Any ideas on how to avoid the second click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that you are not removing the active class when you click on an other element. Now, I can't certify this will work since i can't test it, but i'm pretty sure that is you change the `else` condition to that :

```
else {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  hideAll();
  $(this).nextUntil('hr').slideDown();
}
```

it will work.

Comment: I really **REALLY** hate it when I miss the obvious. Which is often. Thanks for the fresh eyes; I can always count on SO for the right way forward. That did it. Fixed. THANKS!